# Opening port 587 on Debian running on Google Compute Engine

Tags: linux, debian, firewall, port, google-compute-engine

I'm attempting to use port 587 for my server mailing purposes. However, I can't seem to be able to unblock the port even after trying the following :

1. Adding port 587 to the Google Cloud network firewall list
2. Adding a new rule to iptables in the operating system
3. Restart the server

Am I missing out anything?

EDIT:

```
 /etc/iptables.up.rules
 -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
```

AND:

```
 Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes  target     prot opt in     out       source             destination
   7   420   ACCEPT     tcp   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:587
```

Comment: Would be glad if you could point out where the question required a downvote

Comment: *How* did you add the new rule to iptables? Unless you add it to a config file, restarting the server will throw away any changes you have just made. `iptables -L -nv` and `tcpdump -n port 587` are two good debugging tools to figure out where packets are getting to and why they're being dropped. `tcpdump` runs outside `iptables` so if it doesn't see packets, probably the "cloud network firewall" is dropping them instead.

Comment: @Ladadadada Thanks! I have updated the question with the iptables information. However the tcp dumps seems to have no respond capturing 0 packets. Does that mean that the last line of your comment applies?

Comment: That rule doesn't exist in your iptables output but it doesn't matter because your iptables rules are set to accept everything anyway.  It's very likely that the packets are being blocked *before* they get to iptables, so yes, I think it's the "cloud network firewall". Can you get any logging or debugging information from that?

Comment: @Ladadadada I don't seem to see any. Is there other ways I can verify the info?

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation for Google Compute Engine, section ["Networking and Firewalls"](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/networking#blockedtraffic):

> **Blocked traffic**
>
> Google Compute Engine blocks or restricts traffic through all of the
> following ports/protocols between the Internet and virtual machines,
> as well as between two virtual machines when traffic is addressed to
> their public IP addresses (this also includes load-balanced
> addresses).
>
> Note: These restrictions do not apply for traffic between two virtual
> machines through their private addresses.
>
> - All outgoing traffic to port 25 (SMTP) is blocked.
> - Most outgoing traffic to port 465 or **587** (SMTP over SSL) is blocked. except for known [Google IP addresses](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60764)
> - All traffic that uses a protocol other than TCP, UDP, and ICMP is blocked.

I also found ["Sending Email from an Instance"](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/sending-mail):

> Google Compute Engine does not allow outbound connections on ports 25,
> 465, and **587** but you can still set up your instances to send mail
> through ports **587** and 465 using servers provided through partner
> services, such as SendGrid. This document discusses how to set up your
> instances to send email using SendGrid.

Comment: I did came across this post too. May I clarify if my Google Cloud instance IP addressis a'known' Google IP address as described above?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Apologies for the typo. I was asking if my server instance is created as a Google Compute Engine instance, will it be a 'known' Google IP address?

Comment: I don't think so. I think they're referring to servers run _completely_ by them which is not our case, but again, I'm not sure.

Comment: It's pretty obvious that they mean Gmail here.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sorry! I am really new to all this server things and all!

Comment: Are you trying to send email or receive it? The iptables output in the question only covers receiving it.

Comment: The google cloud don't seem to allow us to use smtp port 25 to do handle our mails. Hence, I have used their partner's service Sendgrid to handle the mailing as stated above. Am I right to say that if I were to allow port 587 through my firewall, Sendgrid would handle both receiving and sending?